# GTM Javascript Loop

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I need some help with creating a loop statement. I have the below script in my GTM JS Variable

```
function() {
var productname = {{dataLayer - ecommerce}}.detail.products[0].name; 
return productname;
}
```

The problem here is that i am specifying in my script which product name to take "Products[0]". For example when i have multiple products on a page, it would always return the value for the first product.

I would like to create a loop statement so that it would return all the products name in the variable.

I tried something like this, but does not seem to work.

```
function() {
var productname = []; 
for(var i = 0; i < {{dataLayer - ecommerce}}.detail.products.length; i++){
productname = productname .push({{dataLayer -ecommerce}}.detail.products[i].name);
return productname ;
 }
```

Would someone be able to help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function() {
var productname = []; //empty products Array
var products =  {{dataLayer - ecommerce}}.detail.products; //Array of products
for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
 productname.push(products[i].name);
}

return productname;//Final Array
}
```

The return statement should be placed outside the for loop to ensure all product names are returned instead of just the first one.

Comment: From where did it come {{dataLayer - ecommerce}}.detail.products?

Comment: it is one of my variable in GTM.

Comment: it should be an array of objects @Moe